# How can i make data type just year like 1980 instead of 14.08.1980 at T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a column at Transact Sql and wish to make type of column just year. E.g. 1980 instead of 14.08.1980. Thanks..

Comment: By changing the datatype data will not change. You need to manually update the records to just have year and then alter the data type to small int

Comment: If you want to keep the underlying date, create a new computed column using  [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) or create a view replacing the date column using the same.

Comment: You should include the actual schema definition to get a valid answer. If your column stores a `varchar` or `nvarchar` of the text `14.08.1980` instead of a `datetime` this requires a different solution.

Comment: Filburt 11, How do I add a photo here ?

Comment: Do not use screenshots to post schema information - right-click your table in Sql Mangement Studio and chose "Script as -> CREATE To -> Clipboard" and copy to your post here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql):

```
datepart(year, datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column is `DATETIME`, use `DATEPART()` function:

```
DECLARE @DATES TABLE ( ID INT , VALUE DATETIME);
DECLARE @NUM INT = 3;

WHILE @NUM >=0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @DATES VALUES (@NUM, DATEADD(YY,-@NUM,GETDATE() ) );
        SET @NUM = @NUM -1;
   END

SELECT ID , VALUE , DATEPART( YY , VALUE) [YEAR] FROM @DATES
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

If you refer to `Create Type` then you can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql#examples).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store only Year in the column, then you can use SMALLINT data type. If the input received is in the format of datetime and you want to capture only the year part from it, then use DATEPART(YEAR, DATETIME) in your insert statement to use only the year.

Answer (score 0):

Years are integer values.
Assuming it's only an integer you want and not an actual date you could use something like ...

```
DECLARE @data TABLE ( ID INT , [Year] INT);

INSERT INTO @data [Year] VALUES (1980);

SELECT ID, [Year] FROM @data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the year value is common the last 4 digits you can easily use the following:

`RIGHT(column_name, 4) AS YearValue`